# how do you count and replace a string in a text file that starts at the end of one line and continues on the next using linux commands?

Tags: linux, sed, command-line, grep, command-line-tool

I have a large (4 GB) Windows .csv text file (each lines end in "\r\n") in a Linux environment that was supposed to have been a csv delimited file (delimiter = '|', text qualifier = '"') with each field separated by a pipe and enclosed in double quotes. Any narrative text field with embedded double quotes was supposed to have the double quote escaped with a second double quote (ie. " the quick "brown" fox" was supposed to have been represented as "the quick ""brown"" fox").  Unfortunately escaping the embedded double quotes did not occur.  Further the text fields may include embedded new lines (i.e. Windows CR (\r\n)) which need to be retained.

Sample lines might look as follows:

```
"1234567890123456"|"2016-07-30"|"2016-08-01"|"123"|"456"|"789"|"text narrative field starts\r\n
with text lines that may have embedded double quotes "For example"\r\n
and may include measurements such as 1/2" x 2" with \r\n
the text continuing and includes embedded line breaks \r\n
which will finally be terminated with a double quote"\r\n
"9876543210654321"|"2017-01-31"|"2018-08-01"|"123"|"456"|"789"|"text narrative field"\r\n
"2345678901234567"|"...."\r\n
```

with the objective to have the output appear as follows:

```
~1234567890123456~|~2016-07-30~|~2016-08-01~|~123~|~456~|~789~|~text narrative field starts\r\n
with text lines that may have embedded double quotes ""For example""\r\n
and may include measurements such as 1/2"" x 2"" with \r\n
the text continuing and includes embedded line breaks \r\n
which will finally be terminated with a double quote~\r\n
~9876543210654321~|~2017-01-31~|~2018-08-01~|~123~|~456~|~789~|~text narrative field~\r\n
~2345678901234567~|~....~\r\n
```

The solution I was attempting to implement was to:

1. SUCCESSFUL: change all the "|" sequences to ~|~
2. SUCCESSFUL: change the double quote (")at the start of the first line and end of the last line to a tilde (~)
3. change the ending and starting double quotes to tildes for any lines ending in a double quote at the end of the first line and terminated with a CR (\r\n) (eg. ..."\r\n) and the next line begins with a double quote, followed by 16 digit number and a tilde (eg. "1234567890123456~...) (i.e. it is the start of a new record)
4. convert all remaining double quote characters to two successive double quotes (change " to "")
5. then reverse the first 3 steps above changing all ~ back to double quotes.

I started by using sed to replace all strings with double quote, followed by a pipe, followed by a double quote (i.e. "|") with a tilde, pipe, tilde (i.e. ~|~).  I then manually replaced the first and last doublequote in the file with a tilde.

This is where I ran into issues as I tried to count the number of occurrences where a line ends with a doublequote(") and the start of the next line begins with a doublequote followed by a 16 digit number and a "~" which will tell me the actual number of csv records in the file (minus one) as opposed to the number of lines.  I attempted to do this using grep: `grep '"\r\n"\d{16}~' | wc -l` but that didn't work

I then need to replace those double quotes wherein a double quote ends a record and the succeeding record begins with a double quote followed by a  16 digit number and a "~" leaving everything else intact.

I tried to use sed: `sed 's/"\r\n"(\d{16}~)/~\r\n~\1' windows_file.txt` but it is not working as hoped.

I would welcome any recommendations as to how to accomplish the above.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: sample input and output added along with additional (hopefully) clarifying comments

Answer (score 0):

The script below does what you expect using awk, except for the very last line in the file since it does not know where that record ends.
It could be fixed counting lines in the file but would be impractical since it's a big file.
Looking at data structure records are separated by `"\r\n"` and fields by `"|"` let's use that with `awk`.

```bash
gawk 'BEGIN{ 
    RS="\"\r\n\""  # input record separator RS, 2 double quotes with a DOS line ending in the middle
    FS="\"\\|\""   # input field separator FS, 2 double quotes with a pipe in the middle
    ORS="~\r\n~"   # your record separator
    OFS="~|~"      # your field separator
} {
    $1=$1 # trick awk into believing something has changed
    if (NR == 1){  # first record, replace first character
        print "~" substr($0,2) 
    }else{
        print $0
    } 
} ' test.txt
```

Result (assuming lines end with \r\n):

```
~1234567890123456~|~2016-07-30~|~2016-08-01~|~123~|~456~|~789~|~text narrative field starts
with text lines that may have embedded double quotes "For example"
and may include measurements such as 1/2" x 2" with 
the text continuing and includes embedded line breaks 
which will finally be terminated with a double quote~
~9876543210654321~|~2017-01-31~|~2018-08-01~|~123~|~456~|~789~|~text narrative field~
~10654321~|~2018-09-31~|~2018-08-01~|~123~|~456~|~789~|~asdasdasdasdad asasda"
~
~
```

PS: will break if a field contains a line that starts with `"` and the preceding line within the same ends with `"\r\n` since the pattern will match the proposed RS.

```
"10654321"|"2018-09-31"|"2018-08-01"|"123"|"456"|"789"|"asdasdasdasdad asasda"\r\n
"some more"\r\n
"22222"|".... (another record)
```